# Get title name of the column by RecRef

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

RecRef is datatype of RecRef, and by this i access to table and can select the field of the table;

RecRef.OPEN(IDTABLE); RecRef.field(2); -> RETURN THE FIELD DATA OF THE IDTABLE.

but now i want to take; Title name of the column and number of columns, of the table

Thanks in advance,

EDIT

Is possible whit RecRef.FIELD(IndexVal).CAPTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use FieldRef to this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301382.aspx